# Is there a shorter way too write this function without a big IF statetement

Tags: javascript

Since every statement is 99% the same there must be a way to make it smaller or more efficient

```js
function statistiekMaken() {
  var forbegin_z,forend_z,forby_z;
  forbegin_z = 0;
  forend_z = 49;
  forby_z = 1;
  for(z=forbegin_z;forby_z>=0?z<=forend_z:z>=forend_z;z=z+forby_z){
      if (getArrayValue(springers,z,1) == 'A') {
          statistieken[0][0] = (getArrayValue(statistieken,0,0) + 1);
      statistieken[0][1] = (getArrayValue(statistieken,0,1) + getArrayValue(springers,z,2));} else if (getArrayValue(springers,z,1) == 'B') {
          statistieken[1][0] = (getArrayValue(statistieken,1,0) + 1);
      statistieken[1][1] = (getArrayValue(statistieken,1,1) + getArrayValue(springers,z,2));} else if (getArrayValue(springers,z,1) == 'C') {
          statistieken[2][0] = (getArrayValue(statistieken,2,0) + 1);
      statistieken[2][1] = (getArrayValue(statistieken,2,1) + getArrayValue(springers,z,2));} else if (getArrayValue(springers,z,1) == 'D') {
          statistieken[3][0] = (getArrayValue(statistieken,3,0) + 1);
      statistieken[3][1] = (getArrayValue(statistieken,3,1) + getArrayValue(springers,z,2));} else if (getArrayValue(springers,z,1) == 'E') {
          statistieken[4][0] = (getArrayValue(statistieken,4,0) + 1);
      statistieken[4][1] = (getArrayValue(statistieken,4,1) + getArrayValue(springers,z,2));}
    }
}
```

Comment: in your specific case you can just transform the condition as the index you are going to use in your `statistieken` array doing something like: `[...'ABCDE'][getArrayValue(springers, z, 1)]` and than use that number in those 2 spots where you use it removing the whole if block entirely and solving your algorithm with 2 lines of code

Comment: first thing I'd do is set variables up for `getArrayValue(springers, z, 1)` and `getArrayValue(springers, z, 2)` to DRY your code a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
function statistiekMaken() {
    var forbegin_z, forend_z, forby_z;
    forbegin_z = 0;
    forend_z = 49;
    forby_z = 1;
    for (
        z = forbegin_z;
        forby_z >= 0 ? z <= forend_z : z >= forend_z;
        z = z + forby_z
    ) {
        switch (getArrayValue(springers, z, 1)) {
            case "A":
                statistieken[0][0] = getArrayValue(statistieken, 0, 0) + 1;
                statistieken[0][1] =
                    getArrayValue(statistieken, 0, 1) +
                    getArrayValue(springers, z, 2);
                break;
            case "B":
                statistieken[1][0] = getArrayValue(statistieken, 1, 0) + 1;
                statistieken[1][1] =
                    getArrayValue(statistieken, 1, 1) +
                    getArrayValue(springers, z, 2);
                break;

            case "C":
                statistieken[2][0] = getArrayValue(statistieken, 2, 0) + 1;
                statistieken[2][1] =
                    getArrayValue(statistieken, 2, 1) +
                    getArrayValue(springers, z, 2);
                break;

            case "D":
                statistieken[3][0] = getArrayValue(statistieken, 3, 0) + 1;
                statistieken[3][1] =
                    getArrayValue(statistieken, 3, 1) +
                    getArrayValue(springers, z, 2);
                break;

            case "E":
                statistieken[4][0] = getArrayValue(statistieken, 4, 0) + 1;
                statistieken[4][1] =
                    getArrayValue(statistieken, 4, 1) +
                    getArrayValue(springers, z, 2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Only thing i can think of to prevent the same if statement everytime is a switch.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using an array for column mapping

```js
function statistiekMaken() {
  var forbegin_z,forend_z,forby_z;
  forbegin_z = 0;
  forend_z = 49;
  forby_z = 1;
  const columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
  for(z=forbegin_z;forby_z>=0?z<=forend_z:z>=forend_z;z=z+forby_z){
      const column = getArrayValue(springers,z,1)
      const index = columns.indexOf(column)
      if(index === -1){
       console.error(`Missing column ${column}`)
       continue;
      }
      statistieken[index][0] = (getArrayValue(statistieken,index,0) + 1)
      statistieken[index][1] = (getArrayValue(statistieken,index,1) + getArrayValue(springers,z,2))
   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing I'd do is set variables up for getArrayValue(springers, z, 1) and getArrayValue(springers, z, 2) to DRY your code a bit

Then use indexOf to find then "index" for A, B, C, D or E
So, something like

```
function statistiekMaken() {
    var forbegin_z,
    forend_z,
    forby_z;
    forbegin_z = 0;
    forend_z = 49;
    forby_z = 1;
    for (z = forbegin_z; forby_z >= 0 ? z <= forend_z : z >= forend_z; z = z + forby_z) {
        const one = getArrayValue(springers, z, 1);
        const two = getArrayValue(springers, z, 2);
        const index = 'ABCDE'.indexOf(one);
        if (index >=0) {
            statistieken[index][0] = (getArrayValue(statistieken, index, 0) + 1);
            statistieken[index][1] = (getArrayValue(statistieken, index, 1) + two);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function statistiekMaken() {
    var forbegin_z, forend_z, forby_z;
    forbegin_z = 0;
    forend_z = 49;
    forby_z = 1;
    c = getArrayValue(springers, z, 2);
    d = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
    e = [[0,0,0,1],[1,0,1,1],[2,0,2,1],[4,0,4,1]];
    
    for (z = forbegin_z; forby_z >= 0 ? z <= forend_z : z >= forend_z; z = z + forby_z) {
        f = d.indexOf(getArrayValue(springers, z, 1));
            statistieken[e[f][0]][e[f][1]] = (getArrayValue(statistieken, e[f][0], e[f][1]) + 1);
            statistieken[e[f][2]][e[f][3]] = (getArrayValue(statistieken, e[f][2], e[f][3]) + c);
    }
}
```

Forgive the short named variables (`c,d,e,f`) Just wanted to clean things up.